# Constructor and objects of static inner class

Tags: java

```
public class SomeClass {
  //Some code
  private static InnerClass {
    String test;
    private InnerClass(String test) {
      this.test = test;
    }

    // Using test here in some way
    test.split("something"); //Compiler error, test might not have been initialized
}
```

Why does the compiler complain about that? I am initializing `test` in the constructor. If the compiler is complaining, that means there might be a way to access `test` without going through the constructor. I tried that, but no luck without reflection. What am I missing here?

Comment: Is this your full code? Or you selected only parts of it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

statement

```
 test.split("something");
```

should be in executable block (method/ constructor/ static initilization blocks)

Answer (score 0):

write new method and move this operation into it.

ex :

```
private void splitTest() {
test.split("something");
}
```